# Automatic change kafka topic partition leader

Tags: apache-kafka

I have an issue with my Kafka cluster.
I have 3 brokers, so when I stop the broker 1 (for example), each topic partition  with leader 1 change his leader with the seconde broker in replica configuration.
So this is the good behavior and it works fine.

But when I restart the broker 1 I need to execute:

`./kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh  --zookeeper myHost`

because the current leader is the other replica.

So my question is :
there is a way to configure Kafka to do it automatically ?

thx

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming your default (when all brokers are running) assignment is balanced, and the preferred leaders are evenly spread.

Yes Kafka can re-elect the preferred leaders for all the partitions automatically when a broker is restarted. This is actually enabled by default, see `auto.leader.rebalance.enable`.

Upon restarting a broker, Kafka can take up to `leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds` to trigger the re-election. This defaults to 5 minutes. So maybe you just did not wait long enough!

There is also `leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage` which defines the percentage of non-preferred leaders allowed. This default to 10%.

For the full details about these configuration, see the [broker config section](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) on Kafka's website.

Comment: thx @Mickael for your response:
I was waiting more than 5 minutes, so I think the bad balance is caused by `leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentages` so I will change it to 0.